# Variables for images

Tags: javascript, html, image, variables

im trying to make a switch wich will change two images. I once solved ths, but then i lost some important files, the one containing the final script being one.

The idea is that when the button is clicked, it will change image 1 for image 2 and will change its own image from on to off. Then, when clicked again it will change image 2 for image 1 and its own image from off to on. 
I been trying something like this, buts not working, not sure why. I think i got the wrong declaration for the if which determines if the switch is on or off, but again not sure.

Before you read the code and realize its poorly done, consider i dont know a thing about javascript, i only have a vague idea of how it works.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var vswitch = false;
    if (document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif") {
        vswitch = true
    }
    else {
        vswitch = false
    }

    function change(){
        if (vswitch == true){
            function changelamp() {
                document.getElementById("lamp").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image2.png";
            }

             function changeSwitch() {
                document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/off.gif";
            }
        } else {
            function changelamp() {
                document.getElementById("lamp").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image1.gif";
            }

             function changeSwitch() {
                document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif";
            }
        }
    }
    <div id="main_img">
        <img id="lamp" src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image1.gif">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <img id="switchh" src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif" onclick='change();'>
    </div>
</script>
```

Thank you

/////////////////////EDIT///////////////////////////
Thanks a lot.
Having those two functions there was a result of the previous code, i dont understand how i didnt realize it until you pointed out, heh. (Sleepyness maybe?)
@renuka, that code worked perfectly. I only changed the calling div, from the div "toggle" you created to the div "container" since the button has to switch the images itself, but other than that was sweet. Thanks.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jasonscript You modified the OP's code with a suggestive placement for `</script>` this should not be done in order for others who may visit this question and realize that there may not have been anything wrong with it. Your edit has been rolled back. In the future, DO NOT modify posted code, only apparent grammar/spelling mistakes.

Comment: I rolled back the latest edit because it "fixed" the code. With such a fix answers can not point out the problem that was "fixed". @Fred: sorry, I didn't see you were already on it. :)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I think you and I were doing the rollback at approximately the same time, thanks. @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the updated code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change(){
   var vswitch = false;
   if (document.getElementById("switchh").src == "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif") {
     vswitch = true
   }
   else {
     vswitch = false
   }
   if (vswitch == true){
     document.getElementById("lamp").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image2.png";
     document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/off.gif";
   }
   else {
     document.getElementById("lamp").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image1.gif";
     document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif";
   }
}
</script>
<div id="main_img">
    <img id="lamp" src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image1.gif"/>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <img id="switchh" src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif"/>
</div>
<div id="toggle">
    <input type="button" value="On/Off" onclick='change();'/>
</div>
```

The '`=`' assigns the value to the "src" of the image. Replace it with '`==`' for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here :)

**First:**

```
if (document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif")
                                           ^ this assigns a variable
```

You want to change `=` to `===` so that a comparison is done

**Second**, you're creating functions `changelamp` and `changeSwitch` but you're never actually calling them. I think you want to get rid of the function declarations completely:

```
if (vswitch == true){
    document.getElementById("lamp").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image2.png";
    document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/off.gif";
} else {
    document.getElementById("lamp").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/image1.gif";
    document.getElementById("switchh").src = "http://www.sampleweb.com/on.gif";
}
```

**Finally**, there are some minor syntax errors such as missing semi-colons

```
vswitch = true;    // <- like this
```

Comment: silly me, thanks 
also i didnt know about the diference between equal signs, thanks for that too ^^

Answer (score 0):

Additionally from what jasonscript says, you are never switching the vswitch variable to the opposite state, so you'd need to add

```
vswitch = !vswitch;
```

after the `if` in the `change()` function, that way, the next time you click in the switch, it takes the "other" path through the `if`

Another point is that if you have the code layout as you have it in your post (script first and then the HTML code) the first `if` will actually not find the #switchh img, so you need to either move the `if` inside the `change()` function or move your script after the HTML

Comment: good point, I think that whole if statement should be moved into the `change()` function

Comment: That would work too, but you don't really need to make the comparison, just need to keep the `vswitch` in sync with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Major problem is that you are unnecessarily creating functions inside script which are never called.

No need for

```
changelamp() and changeSwitch()
```

You can directly post the code after the if condition check.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` tags should be closed.  `=` assigns and `===` does comparison, and you need to change the value of vswitch.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YJsfw/) is a fiddle that accomplishes what you're after with some random images